# Laravel 5 update form using plain HTML

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

In Laravel 5, I notice that whenever I have a form in which I wrote in plain HTML, instead of using the `Form::open`, it is required to have a hidden input field for the token.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" />
```

And for a form that updates a record, it is required to have `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">`

Is it correct that I should always have these fields when writing forms using plain HTML? Is there other ways of doing this if I were still to write it in plain HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct. For PATCH (and basically all non GET or POST verbs) there's no other way than using the `_method`.

This is described in the route chapter of the documentation: [Method Spoofing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#method-spoofing)

However you *could* disable CSRF protection. I'm not saying you should do that but if you wanted to, you can disable it by removing `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` from the middleware array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

This is in the documentation as well: [CSRF Protection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection)

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering why is that this is not included in the documentation? I mean, when the developer does not want to use the `Form` helper and decides to use plain HTML, these fields are required. Or is it written and I just missed it?

Comment: Yep it's both in the docs. I'v added the links to me answer :)

Comment: Note that those fields are not required for every form. It depends if you enabled CSRF protection and if you want to target a different method than POST or GET.